# How do I get the latest version of QGIS to find my plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, update

I just downloaded QGIS 3.12.2-București for the Mac (MacOS Mojave 10.14.6, 3.2 GHz with 32 GB ram).  I've been running an older version (QGIS 2.18.2-Las Palmas) for a couple of years and have quite a few plugins for it.  How do I get the new version to locate and recognize the plugins I have already downloaded?

Comment: Are you speaking about self developed plugins or downloaded ones?

Answer (score 1):

You need to redownload the updated versions of them. You can not use QGIS 2 plugins with QGIS 3 because there were some major changes, for example QGIS 3 uses Python 3 and PyQT 5. See https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html for more details. Some of the old plugins may not have been updated for QGIS 3. The only chance to get them is to wait (but maybe forever) or [update them yourself](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3). The other (more convenient) option is to just use QGIS 2.18 and 3.X at the same time.